# Convert *stereo* .mov to mono .mp3?

Tags: audio, video, quicktime, mp3

I need an easy way to take a stereo .mov file and convert it to a mono .mp3 or similar formatted audio file.

I use Ecamm's Skype Call recorder to record interviews, which I send out for transcription. The call recorder creates an .mov file with 2 channels--one for each side of the call. The transcription software only plays one channel, so the audio sounds like it's one sided.

I do this a lot, so I'd like a simple, one-step way to merge the channels and convert the file.

I've tried ffmpeg, which I like, but I'm only getting one channel when I do this:

```
ffmpeg -i call.mov -ac 1 call.mp3
```

Any suggestions? I'd like to use ffmpeg if possible, but a GUI app would be fine as long as it's pretty simple to use.

Comment: I don't have a .mov file around to try, but [this](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) might help

Answer (score 2):

[Max](http://sbooth.org/Max/) (freeware) can drop stereo to mono - though I'm not certain if it will take .mov as input (never tested it). You might need to convert it to a distinct audio format first.

[image]

Comment: Dang, looks like it can't handle .mov files. Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Comment: if ffmpeg can get it over to any type of stereo audio, Max could do the rest. 2-step, but unless someone finds a free alternative...

Comment: If I can get it into a stereo audio format, ffmpeg can handle merging the channels. So the problem is really going from stereo video to mono audio.

Comment: ahh, right, I see. Sorry, other than high-end pro-audio stuff [I do music to picture for a living, but using appropriately costly tools], then it's not something I've tried. Wish you luck, though :)